# Problemas com retorno de dados MYSQL via include no PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou começando um código para um controle de almoxarifado utilizando PHP e MYSQL, e ao fazer um documento de **funções** separado do index.php e realizar as devidas inserções de variáveis via **include** devidamente declarado no **head** do index.php e chamar a variável **$colunas**, esta não retorna todo o conteúdo da minha tabela no MYSQL, somente repete várias vezes a primeira linha da tabela referira.

Seguem os códigos:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head lang="pt-br">
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo_alm.css"/>
        <link onscroll="">
        <title>index.php</title>
        <?php include 'funcoes.php'; ?>
    </head>

    <body id="corpo">
        <header id="cabecalho">
            <h1>Projeto Almoxarifado ADVEC</h1>
            <nav id="menuPags">
                <ul type="disc">
                    <li><a class="pags" href="index.php">controle de material</a></li>
                    <li><a class="pags" href="controle_material.php">pedido de material</a></li>
                    <li><a class="pags" href="controle_notas.php">controle de notas</a></li>
                    <li><a class="pags" href="saida_material.php">saída de material</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="titulo_principal">
            <nav id="menuTabela">
                <ul type="disc">
                    <li><a class="tabela" href="index.php">controle de material</a></li>
                    <li><a class="tabela" href="controle_material.php">pedido de material</a></li>
                    <li><a class="tabela" href="controle_notas.php">controle de notas</a></li>
                    <li><a class="tabela" href="saida_material.php">saída de material</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="principal">
                <table id="tabela2">
                    <?php
                        while($colunas): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="td"><?php echo utf8_encode($colunas['idcidade']); ?></td>
                                <td id="td1"><?php echo utf8_encode($colunas['cidade']); ?></td>
                                <td id="td2"><?php echo utf8_encode($colunas['estado']); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </section>
        <aside id="menuBotoes">
            <ul type="disc">
                <li><a class="botoes" href="index.php">controle de material</a></li>
                <li><a class="botoes" href="controle_material.php">pedido de material</a></li>
                <li><a class="botoes" href="controle_notas.php">controle de notas</a></li>
                <li><a class="botoes" href="saida_material.php">saída de material</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <footer id="rodape">
        </footer>
        <?php $conecta->close(); ?>
    </body>
</html>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head lang="pt-br">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>funcoes_almox.php</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    define("SERVIDOR", "localhost");
    define("USUARIO", "root");
    define("SENHA", "");
    define("BANCODEDADOS", "controle_almoxarifado_v02");

    $conecta = new mysqli(SERVIDOR, USUARIO, SENHA, BANCODEDADOS);
    if ($conecta->connect_error) {
        trigger_error("ERRO NA CONEXÃO: " . $conecta->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $selecao_geral = mysqli_query($conecta, 'select * from cidade');
    $colunas = $selecao_geral->fetch_assoc();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coloca o include antes do doctype

Comment: Coloquei mas não deu resultado diferente.

Comment: Primeiro, qual o motivo de estar criando documento  `html` no include?

Comment: Opa! Mesmo com corpo HTML o documento é php, mas como foi a primeira vez que postei algo aqui e não tenho experiência em postar códigos, não estava conseguindo colocar somente o php do funcoes_almox.php e como vi que o código do index.php entrou, coloque igual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituia `while($colunas):` por `while($colunas = $selecao_geral->fetch_assoc()):` para atualizar o valor de $colunas a cada interação. O fetch_assoc() movimenta o ponteiro no resultado da query em cada chamada para a função, e você precisa atualizar o valor de $colunas, senão ele vai sempre ficar salvo com o primeiro valor encontrado (mesmo que o while percorra todo o resultado da query).

Comment: Funcionou perfeito!  Mas deixa fazer uma outra pergunta.  Como utilizar como uma função onde eu somente insira somente o conteúdo de variáveis e ele retorne o valor, de forma que eu possa repetir a função em várias situações?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer. Você pode mostrar algum exemplo?
A propósito, se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, não esquece de marcar ela como aceita ;)

Comment: Opa! Como faço pra aceitar a resposta? Então, acho que me expressei mau. Quero saber como posso colocar esse código php que faz a leitura do conteúdo do banco de dados como uma função, que quando eu chamar ela e passar os argumentos, ela possa me retornar o conteúdo sem tem que declarar a função várias vezes nos documentos php de um mesmo projeto de site.

Comment: Tente usar `$selecao_geral->fetchAll()` fora do while e ele deve funcionar. 
Sobre a resposta, segue link com esclarecimentos:
https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta